# iOS: Dismiss presented ViewController which is an instance of specific Class

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using [NYAlertViewController](https://github.com/nealyoung/NYAlertViewController) to display dialogs in my iOS-App. It can happen that I just opened a dialog when a background process tries to trigger another dialog. If this happens, the second dialog is not shown. I would like to close all other dialogs before opening a new one. How could I do this?

The Dialogs are shown with `presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion`.

Maybe I can dismiss all ViewControllers that are instances of NYAlertViewController?

Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: You should share some code so we can help. However one phrase caught my attention: "background process tries to trigger another dialog" -> no background thread can trigger UI changes

Comment: @ppaulojr I recieve a notification from (firebase messaging) and this triggers a dialog on the current context. My code is totally irrelevant as I am just using the pod as inteded. It is more of a conceptional question how to dismiss all viewcontrollers that are instances of a specific parent class.